# Disable Unified Messaging

Tags: powershell

I'm building a user archiving script and would like some help with disabling unified messaging for a user. I would like to include a check in to see if the user has got unified messaging enabled before disabling it, so that I can avoid errors.

Currently this is what I have:

```
$username = Read-host "Enter uSername"
Disable-UMMailbox -Identity $username
```

Comment: Ive figuired it our guys. Here is the script.                                   $username = Read-host "Enter uSername"

if ( Get-Mailbox -Identity $username | where-object {$_.UMEnabled -eq $true})

{

 Disable-UMMailbox -Identity $username

}
else
{

Write-Host "no voicemail enabled"
}

Comment: Thanks. I have just done it.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it our guys. Here is the script:

```
$username = Read-host "Enter uSername"
if ( Get-Mailbox -Identity $username | where-object {$_.UMEnabled -eq $true}) {
  Disable-UMMailbox -Identity $username
} else {
  Write-Host "no voicemail enabled"
}
```